# how to solve MySQL server has gone away in python

Tags: python, mysql

My code need to query mysql for many times to get data from mysql,in order to save time, i only reconnect mysql a short before mysql time_wait is up or when connection is broken,

class MonitorBase(object):
    """
    监控类的父类
    """

```
# 记录各对象和连接
mysql_util = None
palo_util = None
mysql_link = None
palo_link = None

# 最大重试次数
max_retry_times = 3

# 记录最大的连接保持时间，和mysql配置有关系
mysql_max_keepalive_time = palo_max_keepalive_time = 240

# 记录连接时间
mysql_connect_time = None

palo_connect_time = None

@classmethod
def get_mysql_connect(cls):
    """
    获取数据库连接
    :return:
    """

    if cls.mysql_connect_time is None:
        # 第一次调用，连接数据库
        cls.mysql_util = mysqlUtil2.MysqlUtil()
        tmp = cls.max_retry_times
        conn = None
        while (conn is None and tmp > 0):
            conn = cls.mysql_util.getConnection()
            tmp -= 1

        if conn is None:
            logging.error('无法连接到数据库')
            exit(-1)

        cls.mysql_link = conn
        cls.mysql_connect_time = int(time.time())
        return conn

    current = int(time.time())
    if cls.mysql_connect_time + cls.mysql_max_keepalive_time <= current:
        # 需要保活了
        try:
            cls.mysql_link.ping()
            cls.mysql_connect_time = int(time.time())
        except:
            # 关闭数据库之后再重连
            cls.mysql_link.close()
            # 连接数据库
            tmp = cls.max_retry_times
            conn = None
            while (conn is None and tmp > 0):
                conn = cls.mysql_util.getConnection()
                tmp -= 1

            if conn is None:
                logging.error('无法连接到数据库')
                exit(-1)
            cls.mysql_link = conn
            cls.mysql_connect_time = int(time.time())

    return cls.mysql_link
@classmethod
def get_data_from_mysql(cls, sql):
    """
    获取mysql数据
    :param sql:
    :return:
    """
    conn = cls.get_mysql_connect()
    curs = conn.cursor()
    logging.info('mysql开始查询,sql: ' + sql)
    try:
        mysqlData = cls.mysql_util.doSearch(sql, curs)
    except:
        logging.error('mysql库查询执行错误' + sql)
        exit(-1)

    cls.mysql_util.close(curs)
    logging.info('mysql查询成功')
    return mysqlData
```

and when i run my script,it show me

OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))")

what is wrong with my code?